# Does the percentage of groups of order at most $n$ of even order aproach $1$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $E_n$ be the number of isomorphism classes of groups of even order at most $n$, let $G_n$ be the number of isomorphism classes of groups of order at most $n$ and $T_n$ be the number of isomorphism classes of $2$-groups of order less than $n$.

I think that it is an open problem if $\frac{T_n}{G_n}$ approaches $1$, so I figured that it is probably not so hard to prove that $\frac{E_n}{G_n}$ approaches $1$, although I was not able to do so.

Comment: I think you mean "number of *isomorphism* classes" (not automorphism classes).

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad

Comment: I think that using these bounds [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422120/known-bounds-for-the-number-of-groups-of-a-given-order) we can show that almost all primes have order not-coprime to $N!$ for sufficiently large $N$ ( we need that $\log(N) > \frac{27}{2}$) I think.

Comment: I think  this is proved by O'brein and others: almost all groups of order $\leq n$ are 2-groups.

Comment: really? because I think that was posted as an open problem at the end of the book I skimmed while gathering the bounds I used. Although that book is from $2007$

Comment: I remembered where I saw this: three years ago (on Oct 28, 2013) there was a discussion in the facebook page (Irmath) about this problem and one of the members was announced it with a link to O'brien's website. Now I see it is not proved (at least that reference does not contain such a result).

Comment: "Almost every group is a $2$-group" is still a conjecture; it is discussed in the more general, and quite relevant, question posed at [**MO 150603**](http://mathoverflow.net/q/150603).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following works:

Looking at the book [enumeration of finite groups](https://www.cambridge.org/vu/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/enumeration-finite-groups?localeText=Vanuatu&locale=bi_VU&query=),

We obtain that the number of groups of order $p^k$ is at least: $$\frac{p^{\frac{2m^3}{27}}}{p^{\frac{2}{3}m^2}}$$

We also obtain that the number of groups of order $n$ is:

$$n^{\frac{2\mu^2}{27}}n^{\mathcal O(\mu^{3/2})}$$

where $\mu$ is the largest exponent for a prime power dividing $N$.

So take a natural $N$, and suppose that $2^m$ is the largest power of $2$ not exceeding $N$, we obtain that the number of groups of order $2^m$ is at least:

$$\frac{2^{\frac{2m^3}{27}}}{2^{\frac{2}{3}m^2}}=\frac{(2^m)^{\frac{2}{27}m^2}}{(2^m)^{\frac{2}{3}m}}\geq\frac{N^{\frac{2m^2}{27}}}{N^{\frac{2}{3}m}2^{\frac{2m^2}{27}}}\geq \frac{N^{\frac{2m^2}{27}}}{N^m}$$

On the other hand, if $n$ is an odd integer less than $N$, clearly its $\mu$ is at most $m\log_3(2)+1$. For large values of $m$ we can just bound this by $\alpha m$, for some pre-selected $\alpha<1$.

So the number of groups of odd order is :

$$N(N^{\frac{2\alpha^2 m^2}{27}}N^{\mathcal O(m^{3/2})})$$.

So the fraction between the number of groups of order $2^m$ and the number of groups of odd order less than $N$ for large $N$ is at least:

$$\frac{N^{\frac{2m^2}{27}}}{N^mN(N^{\frac{2\alpha m^2}{27}}N^{\mathcal O(m^{3/2})})}=N^{\frac{2(1-\alpha^2)m^2}{27}-\mathcal O(m^{3/2})}$$

Which clearly goes to infinity.